# Vectorize Loop Using Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two 1D Numpy arrays `index_data` and `charge`, which are the same length and contain ints and floats respectively. I am trying to make a `total_charge` array as follows:

```
total_charge = []
for i in range(len(index_data)):
    if index_data[i] == 0:
        total_charge.append(charge[i])
    else:
        total_charge[-1] += charge[i]
total_charge = np.array(total_charge)
```

How would I vectorize this? Help me Numpy wizards, you're my only hope.

Comment: I don't think this lends itself to vectorization very easily ...

Comment: A Star Wars reference from Mr. Spock?  No, that's just not right. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A concrete example of `index_data` and `charge` would help clarify the expected input.  From reading what you have, however, I think using `np.add.reduceat` can be used.

Apparently each new group of charges is indicated by a `0` in `index_data`; otherwise, the values in `index_data` are not used.  `total_charge` is the sum of the charges in each group.

Here's an example of how `reduceat` could be used.

First, some demo data:

```
In [105]: index_data
Out[105]: array([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])

In [106]: charge
Out[106]: array([ 1.5,  2. ,  3. ,  2.5,  1.5,  1. ,  1. ,  2. ,  1. ])
```

`zerolocs` gives the indices where `0` occurs in `index_data`:

```
In [107]: zerolocs = where(index_data==0)[0]

In [108]: zerolocs
Out[108]: array([0, 3, 7])
```

Use `np.add.reduceat` to sum the charge groups.

```
In [109]: total_charge = np.add.reduceat(charge, zerolocs)

In [110]: total_charge
Out[110]: array([ 6.5,  6. ,  3. ])
```

Comment: You are a miracle worker. I knew there was some obscure Numpy function that would do exactly what I wanted, I just didn't know which one. And hey, us Trekkies can still appreciate Star Wars.